# obd2 Bluetooth connection to Android API

Tags: android, obd-ii

I am a new to Android programming and I have an exercise to make a simple Android app that connected with obd2 via Bluetooth and sending data.

My question firstly is if my app till now can searching the obd2  e.g. `00:0D:18:A0:43:01`. What are the next steps to establish this connection?

I have read about this at Developers and many topics here. I will show my code if you want.

Answer (score 0):

because i am doing this project till now 2 months,i got the first response especially for rpm ("010C") and the response was "41 0C 10 C7" in hex. The last 2 bytes(10 C7) when you convert them to decimal form and divide /4 you will get your properly answer!!This could be the same for 010D speed and all the others obd commands.If you want further informations you can send here and ill be happy to help.